# I need to filter my data for specific latitude and longitude from a text file using python syntax

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, text

I have gridded emission .txt files which are in multiple folders, each .txt file has more than 1 million rows so excel can't open it and I need to filter data in each .txt file for specific latitude and longitude.
Here I want to give a path for the folder so python can read each file from a folder and filter the data for the specific lat long

```py
import pandas as pd

with open(r"C:\Users\VOC_spec_.txt",'r') as f2:
    data = f2.read()
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lat', 'lon', 'emission'])  # create the dataframe
    df_sub = subset(df, Lat >= 28 & Lat <= 33 & Long >= 75 & Long <= 97)
```

this gives an error name 'subset' is not defined

Does anyone know how to write it efficiently and save in .txt format. It will be great help

Comment: With this code you are creating an empty dataframe (df)

Answer (score 0):

`subset` is a function from `R`. Pandas has some options as `query`:

```
df_sub=df.query('lat >= 28 & lat <= 33 & lon >= 75 & lon <= 97')
```

Or you can also use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/indexing.html):

```
df_sub=df[(df['lat']>=28) & (df['lat']<=33) &(df['lon']>=75) &(df['lon']<=97) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it without Dataframes:

```py
with open(r"C:\Users\VOC_spec_.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read().strip(" \n").split("\n")

filtered = []
for line in data:
    l = line.split(',')
    lat, long, em = float(l[0].strip()), float(l[1].strip()), float(l[2].strip())
    if lat >= 28 and lat <= 33 and long >= 75 and long <= 97:
        filtered.append([lat, long, em])
```

Now `filtered` only contains the matching lines. Note that I split each line with `','` assuming your CSV is comma-delimited. Replace that with the delimiter matching your file.